# MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified. Switch: Studio

Tags: c#-4.0

```
private void GetExeFile(string link)
{
    Process compiler = new Process();
    compiler.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe";
    compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = link + @"‪C:\Users\khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Calculator\Calculator.sln /t:build /r:System.dll /out:sample.exe stdstr.cs";
    compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    compiler.Start();
    txtGetContent.Text = compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    compiler.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Please use the preview to help you check that the post is formatted correctly before posting it.

Comment: Please look at : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

You need to quote the solution filename because it has spaces in:

```
compiler.StartInfo.Arguments = link + @"‪""C:\Users\khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Calculator\Calculator.sln"" /t:build /r:System.dll /out:sample.exe stdstr.cs";
```

This is just how argument parsing works - it's not really C# specific.

Comment: "msbuild " + @"""C:\Users\khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Calculator\Calculator\Calculator.csproj"" /t:rebuild";
i am facing this error actually same command run in cmd but not  in visual studio

Comment: @ShahzaibKhan: I don't know what you mean... from the command line, you'd run `msbuild "C:\Users\khan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Calculator\Calculator\Calculator.csproj" /t:rebuild` which should be fine.